# Can a car's battery be used as a sacrificial anode?

Tags: electrochemistry

The title of the question says it all. Can I hook the anode of my car's battery up to the car's shell and prevent it from rusting? Also would the car's battery get electrically charged from this?

Comment: If by anode you mean negative terminal, no it won't prevent rusting or charge the battery; the negative terminal is already connected bodies of most cars.

Answer (score 1):

A sacrificial anode must be in direct contact to the corrosive medium and electrically connected the thing it's supposed to save. Your battery sits high and dry under the hood, for good reason. Doesn't work.